# Cross contaminated food

Tags: food, halal-haram

Asalamialaykum, I just have a question that I need answering please. So today I ate dominoes but it was a vegitarian pizza no meat was on there but I once read that their food is cross contaminated and dispite knowing that I ate the pizza because there was no meat on there.
So what I want to know is will my prayers be accepted as well as my duas?
And is it okay if I read the the Quran pak?
It’s bothering me now and I don’t know what to do I feel really guilty
Could you please answer this thankyouuu. May Allah reward u

Comment: Allah is the most forgiving, most merciful. At the time of eating, you didn't know the fact. Islam is a very simple religion, why should your prayers not be answered? Why should you stop reading the Quran? Instead, you are making Shaytan happy, and becoming a disbeliever. Here is the simple answer: **Continue praying, continue reading Quran, ask Allah for forgiveness and to guide you to the right path.**

Comment: Thankyou very much for ur answer. But at the time I did know their food may be contaminated so the guilt is eating my peace of mind and I don’t know what to do other than repent sincerely.

Comment: Allah expects us to make mistakes and ask for forgiveness. I recently heard: "If he one commits a sin, then asks the almighty to forgive him, the almighty forgives him. Then he commits the sin once again, once again he asks for forgiveness, the almighty says that he is a human and asking me to forgive, so I will forgive him. Then for the third time he commits the sin again, asks for forgiveness and the almighty forgives him." Us Humans are made to make mistakes. **Continue praying, continue reading Quran, ask Allah for forgiveness and to guide you to the right path**

Comment: May allah bless you for helping me to not over think the situation too much. Thank you very much means a lot :)